# Please solve the error of type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: next.js

Error occurred while using loginType filter.

// interface

```
export interface LoginTypeInterface {
  google: StaticImageData,
  kakao: StaticImageData,
  naver: StaticImageData,
  facebook: StaticImageData,
  apple: StaticImageData,
}

export interface User {
  // other data...,
  loginType?: string;
};
```

// images

```
import icon_facebook from 'image path';
import icon_google from 'image path';
import icon_kakao from 'image path';
import icon_naver from 'image path';
import icon_apple from 'image path';
```

// filter

```
export const loginTypeFilter: LoginTypeInterface = {
  'google': icon_google,
  'kakao': icon_kakao,
  'naver': icon_naver,
  'facebook': icon_facebook,
  'apple': icon_apple,
}
```

// init state

```
const [ myInfo, setMyInfo ] = useState<User>({
    // other data...,
    loginType: 'kakao'
  });
```

// get data

```
axios.get('api path')
.then(res => {
setMyInfo(res.data.data);
}).catch(err => {
// error
})
```

```
<Image src={ loginTypeFilter[myInfo.loginType] } alt="image" objectFit="cover" width={100} height={100} />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Ff2.png)

There is an error when using the filter in the src part of the image tag here.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix

In your `User` interface change the `loginType` to `keyof LoginTypeInterface` instead of `string`.

## Explanation

That's because the `loginType` in your `User` interface is a `string`. As far as the TS compiler is concerned, it can hold any string value. While the `LoginTypeInterface`  interface can only hold one of the 5 defined keys.
Changing the type of `loginType` "informs" the compiler that this field can only hold one of the defined keys of `LoginTypeInterface`, and there's no possibility that you're trying to access a key that doesn't exist.